# Convert 6,5 to number in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, numbers, decimalformat

Given the XML:

```
<quest>
  <g_1>
    <name>first</name>
    <value>4,5</value>
  </g_1>
  <g_2>
    <name>first</name>
    <value>4,5</value>
  </g_2>
</quest>
```

How can I work with value as a number in xsl without using translate to convert , to . ?

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(number(translate(current-group()/VALUE[.!=''],',','.')))" />
```

This will work but I don't like the solution.
I can't help to think that there is a function, for example adding a parameter to the the number() function specifying the ' , ' as decimal-separator while converting or specifying the input locale of the string.

I can't use most functions because the 6,5 is obviously not yet a valid number notation.

Thanks!

Comment: `translate(current-group()/VALUE[.!=''],',','.')` should give an error as soon as there is more then one `VALUE`. I think you rather want `current-group()/VALUE[.!='']/translate(., ',', '.')`.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, I'll add your recommendation, although I rather not depend on translate to convert my 6,5 into a number at all.

Comment: A string that contains any characters other than digits, the decimal dot and the minus sign cannot be converted to a number. You **must** start by changing the decimal comma to a dot.

Answer (score 0):

There are no parameters to `number` or `xs:double` or `xs:decimal` to parse numbers with a different format. So you have to use some string function first to get the right format, whether that is `translate` or `replace` is up to you.